# How to check for row value in previous rows over date-time in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I'd like to take the following data, and check for each day whether the animal was observed the previous day, then create a count per day of new animals observed.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Date': pd.to_datetime(['18/08/2018', '18/08/2018', '18/08/2018', 
                                '19/08/2018', '19/08/2018', '19/08/2018', 
                                '19/08/2018', '19/08/2018', '20/08/2018', 
                                '20/08/2018', '20/08/2018']),
          'Animal':        ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'rabbit', 'rat', 'lion', 'tiger', 'monkey']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

With a result something like:

> ```
>     1. 18/08/2018   3
>     2. 19/08/2018   2
>     3. 20/08/2018   3
> ```

I'm very new to Python, so any help very appreciated! Thx.

Comment: For the 19th wouldn't it be 3? cat, dog and mouse?

Comment: is the check just for the previous day or cumulative for all the previous dates?

Comment: It seems like not cumulative @anky

Comment: Thanks all. 18th = 3, 19th = 2. Only interested in whether they were observed the previous day.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach using [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
s = (pd.Series(pd.factorize(df.Animal)[0]).groupby(df.Date).max()+1)
# decumulate and fill first row
s.diff().fillna(s) 

Date
2018-08-18    3.0
2018-08-19    2.0
2018-08-20    3.0
dtype: float64
```

---

Where by factorizing we are encoding as an enumerated type:

```
pd.factorize(df.Animal)[0]
# array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype=int64)
```

And by grouping by the `Date` and obtaining the `max`, we are getting the acumulated amount of new animals:

```
Date
2018-08-18    3
2018-08-19    5
2018-08-20    8
dtype: int64
```

Now we can just obtain the `diff` to decumulate the `Series`:

Comment: Agreed, very nice. And as I'm new to Python this gives a lot to study on. Anyway, I think there may still be a flaw as OP stricktly mentioned: *Only interested in whether they were observed the previous day.*. If Lion was counted on the first day, it is not counted again on the third at the moment.

Comment: It is @Jvdv because factorize assigns the same number to a repeated string. So it doesnt matter whether it appeared the day before or two days before

Comment: Well, I just gave this a try. Counting a lion on the first day did not count it again on the third day (when on the second day it was not observed). So it should count the lion as "new" on the third day. Well, that's how I read the question anyway. You got my upvote nonetheless for some nice demonstration.

Comment: Hmm I see your point. I'm not sure if that is OPs intention though. But you're right @jvdv

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. On this small set of data, this works, but is there any way to check only the previous day, or X previous days?

Answer (score 3):

Here is another proposal which uses aggregation as set then `shift` and check difference

```
m = df.groupby('Date')['Animal'].agg(set)
n = m.str.len()
n.iloc[1:] = [len(a.difference(b)) for a,b in zip(m,m.shift().fillna(m.head(1)))][1:]
print(n)
```

---

```
print(n)

Date
2018-08-18    3
2018-08-19    2
2018-08-20    3
dtype: int64
```